# Tables are not getting refreshed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the problem in refreshing the table. I create the table like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{

DetailsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*768, 45, 768, 1024) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    DetailsTable.dataSource = self;
    DetailsTable.delegate = self;
    DetailsTable.tag = i + 1;
    [scrollView addSubview:DetailsTable];
    [DetailsTable release];
}
```

**Whenever I am refreshing the table like this [DetailsTable reloadData]; it refresh the last table only. And other table is not getting refresh**

How can refresh all table view in iphone

Comment: please elaborate how your reloading.you should reload all the tables on the scrollview some  example is for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ UItableview **table=(UITableview**)[scrollview viewwithtag:i+1]; [table reloadData];}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because in DetailsTable the last table reference is retain so that this occurs
Try this
add this in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *tblArr;
```

add this in .m file

```
tblArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    UITableView *DetailsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*768, 45, 768, 1024) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    DetailsTable.dataSource = self;
    DetailsTable.delegate = self;
    DetailsTable.tag = i + 1;
    [scrollView addSubview:DetailsTable];
    [tblArr addObject:DetailsTable];
    [DetailsTable release];
}
```

and when you want to relaod all table use this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    [(UITableView *)[tblArr objectAtIndex:i] reloadData];
}
```

Comment: give a tag to each table and then in editing methods of `UITableViewDelegate` perform action by checking the tableView tag value.

Comment: When I do like  that it effect on last table only not to all table how can do explain with sample code

Answer (score 1):

You keep overwriting the value of the PersonDetailsTable property in the loop.  Therefore the value of that property is the 4th one after the loop exits.  You call reloadData against that property which points to the 4th instance of the table you added.

To make that work, you would need an NSMutableArray of table views (instead of the one property reference) and reloading all of them would could be looping with reloadData calls.  Of course in your UITableView datasource callbacks, you need to distinguish between which table view is calling you back for data since self is the datasource and delegate for all of them.

Comment: friend i am refreshing table on the button click .It's just add table on scrollview

Comment: that's fine, but you're calling reloadData on the DetailsTable property reference which points to *only* the 4th (last) table since you overwrite it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

you are creating 4 tableView not four cells, and every time you are creating a new instance of the table so when you call the [DetailsTable reloadData]; it refrences the most recent instance of DetailsTable i.e the last table.

Answer (score 0):

The variable DetailsTable is being replaced with a new one every time in the for loop.

You should create an array of tables instead, like this:

```
//Declaration
UITableView *DetailsTable[4];

//Implementation
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{

DetailsTable[i] = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*768, 45, 768, 1024) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    ...
}

//And to refresh them
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    [DetailsTable[i] reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

put in for loop where you are going to create

```
DetailsTable.tag=i
```

and then for example of edit method of delegate method use this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (tableView.tag)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            //write your code here
            break;
        }
        // like this do all for other remaining tableview
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not add tables like this. Your next tableView will replace the pre tableView. You should impliment this by init four single tables.